# Prevent search changes from spamming history

Tags: javascript, angular.js

This is my solution to my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280069/prevent-search-changes-from-spamming-history/39452369#39452369). My requirements are:

- use links inside of the angular app
- when following a link with the same `path` (i.e., differing in the `search` only), do not add it to the browser history

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    var replacing;

    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
        if (oldUrl === newUrl) {
            return; // Nobody cares.
        }

        // Make urls relative.
        var baseLength = $location.absUrl().length - $location.url().length;
        newUrl = newUrl.substring(baseLength);
        oldUrl = oldUrl.substring(baseLength);

        // Strip search, leave path only.
        var newPath = newUrl.replace(/\?.*/, "");
        var oldPath = oldUrl.replace(/\?.*/, "");

        // Substantial change, history should be written normally.
        if (oldPath !== newPath) {
            return;
        }

        // We're replacing, just let it happen.
        if (replacing) {
            replacing = false;
            return;
        }

        // We're NOT replacing, scratch it ...          
        event.preventDefault();

        // ... and do the same transition with replace later.
        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
            $location.url(newUrl).replace();
            replacing = true;
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: I would consider it to be bad UX to modify the browser's default behaviour. What you're doing makes it impossible to go back to a previous result by pressing the Back button, which is surprising to me as a user.

Comment: @DanPantry That's a good point, but I guess, you don't want to. There's a big list containing some data and the links on which you click in order to see more details. After you do this a few times, the history gets spammed and you have no chance of going back to a *really different place* where you were before. +++ In the previous version, there was the same functionality implemented without URL changes, you could expand an entry (collapsing the previous one) and you could not go back to the previous expansion as it was no history-relevant state at all.